# Is there any reason that AudioEase couldn't make an IR from the Tenman Horn?

Tags: convolution-reverb, ir, altiverb

Just heard about this 80 year old technology making a comeback on NPR this evening. A 27' horn loudspeaker? Yes, I think it would make a great IR:

http://www.stuff.tv/history-s-greatest-loudspeaker-back-business/feature

Is there any reason why it couldn't be made in to one?

Comment: I saw a presentation a couple moths back, it's an awesome and brutal thing. Really loud.

Comment: Sorry: It was not a physical presentation of the Horn.. it was a video and speech by a researcher from England.

Comment: Gosh darnit, I love cultural preservation of spaces through sampled impulses. Have you asked the dudes at Audio Ease?

Comment: From the sound of that article, the horn is unusual because it doesn't colour the sound and its high directivity doesn't allow for early reflections in the room. Unfortunately, that would make for a very boring impulse.

Answer (score 2):

An IR is made from a space, not a source, so at best, you could use that blasted miracle speaker as the source hardware, playing into some space that could be tuned properly for it and produce an IR from that, but you wouldn't technically be capturing the sound of the speaker, but the response of the space into which it's being played.

It is very cool, though, yeah? Good find!

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. You can take an IR of a speaker too, where you end up capturing the frequency response of the system over time, so you can get an IR from a guitar amp or effects processor.